# events no longer getting logged in google analytics?

Tags: javascript, google-analytics

I set up a basic implementation to send an event to GA:

```
ga('send','event','Test', 'UserAction', '12345');
```

I made this explicit call from js several times and the event was logged to GA each time.  Then I wanted to experiment with the last [fieldsObject] param option for the function above so I tried the following line of code:

```
var fieldsObject = {UserId:123,SelectedReportType:1,SelectedRegionId:'TexasRegion'};
ga('send', 'event', 'Test2', 'UserAction', '111', '222', fieldsObject);
```

However, after executing the line of code above from js several times, no events were logged.  I then tried reverting the original line of ga code but no events were logged.

No errors were logged to the Console during execution for ga or unrelated js.  I have the GA debugger plugin installed in Chrome but everything looks fine in the output.  I don't see any GA debugger info that would indicate a problem. Any idea what the problem might be or how to debug?